# Confirmation emails for my MediaWiki subdomain are going straight to spam

Tags: php, email, dns, mediawiki

Need some help diagnosing why conformation emails for my Mediawiki are going straight to spam, had to lock down the Wiki due to bots.
http://wiki.piratemc.com is my wiki address.

Email is needed for account conformation emails.
I'm running SMTP through Googles business servers since email got disabled on my host to send out emails via the local mail server, I assume to stop spam bots being used.

Im using the example from this talk comment in my config:
`https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk:$wgSMTP#Example_using_Google_Mail`

It's got to be a setting with the built in mediawiki, or something to do with me using a subdomain, or DNS? Because all user accounts created on my main website ran by wordpress/buddypress go through fine through the google servers.

Im using Cloudflare to run my DNS, I created an A record and pointed that to my Web hosting IP, and created the sub-domain in cpanel to get the sub-domain setup.

Comment: Do you mean "confirmation", not "conformation"?

Answer (score 0):

Well let's see, I registered on your wiki with a Gmail address and I got:

`Received: by 10.27.93.139 with SMTP id r133csp841052wlb;
        Sun, 26 Jul 2015 03:26:54 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.140.42.98 with SMTP id b89mr33012264qga.78.1437906414160;
        Sun, 26 Jul 2015 03:26:54 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <...@piratemc.com>
Received: from mail-qg0-f46.google.com (mail-qg0-f46.google.com. [209.85.192.46])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id e92si16674252qga.85.2015.07.26.03.26.53
        for <...@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sun, 26 Jul 2015 03:26:54 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of ...@piratemc.com designates 209.85.192.46 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.192.46;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of ...@piratemc.com designates 209.85.192.46 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=...@piratemc.com
Received: by mail-qg0-f46.google.com with SMTP id u79so34137324qge.1
        for <...@gmail.com>; Sun, 26 Jul 2015 03:26:53 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:from:date:message-id:mime-version:content-type
         :content-transfer-encoding:subject:to;
        bh=7DxPJYAXIahN7eGPo8i8huPCfaouA1fa5IpmfMY+DK8=;
        b=PyiE5THk6ai9Rfy3H1nIkJFiyiiGJjMGqq2hlq4mcKdtHnQlcJDJ/JnF0RSI2DI/ms
         VwZ2fbz10/u+skgQ0DzgQC0qbIWRsc5vEF40TWUcvGH5Lu6PKT3JPfaP8t42rwfpeF/M
         RRFwjju7wUM9FjqZaydpgWEtLzwV6EPdOyqvvznVM8rbzAknBC+w2fAs830pd4XT/8a4
         fjD9G5wJW3CLElqS+O9Qp8qfbRKH6/WOvaBRV44N1f5o5ubBGXHGji84Ljz0Q5noaTdU
         tSFukefPKxtd4PT77I1YeKCaC/Y3mZor/AENfjkVh6RdfyuWhfJZa5lZ61xt8FYdJ7MW
         CPaQ==
X-Gm-Message-State: ALoCoQkcwsKyr6WXZQn3SKqAaeIoxryylA6QNULlonPL5AYRSaOIoOjCiZz0nxy6w+kxWUm5xHPN
X-Received: by 10.141.28.139 with SMTP id f133mr13915894qhe.30.1437906413389;
        Sun, 26 Jul 2015 03:26:53 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <...@piratemc.com>
Received: from localhost (panda.abstractdns.com. [205.251.130.98])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id q19sm7062455qha.32.2015.07.26.03.26.51
        for <...@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Sun, 26 Jul 2015 03:26:51 -0700 (PDT)
From: PirateCraft <...@piratemc.com>
Return-Path: ...@piratemc.com
Date: Sun, 26 Jul 2015 10:26:50 +0000`

DKIM and SPF pass, IPs and domains don't seem blocked at https://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/ : that's pretty good!
Maybe you just needed more time to get out of some blacklist after you fixed the configuration?

Alternatively, there might be some content-based spam filter. You should check said spam filter and report back to them that they are blocking legitimate content.